# ios7 and ios6 play youtube video

Tags: ios, youtube-api, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I have found this code to support playing youtube video [link](https://github.com/larcus94/LBYouTubeView), but still can't figure out how to process/handle Done button when player appear. I want to close this player.

Comment: As that class simply derives from `MPMoviePlayerViewController`, handling the done-button would be done exactly as it is with that parent class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think best to ask Author on his [issue page](https://github.com/larcus94/LBYouTubeView/issues)